# Swift - problem when getting documents from Firestore

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

HI I am trying to get some docs from the firestore but I am having some problems.

I have these two functions to get documents that do almost the same thing, the two functions look for a document with .whereField () and sort it with .order ("timestamp")

The problem is that in the first one it works if it brings me the documents that are equal to the field and orders them by their timestamp. But in the second function no, when I only put .whereField() it does bring me the docs but when I add the .orde() it no longer shows me anything.

func() 1 :

```
func fetchUserPosts() {
            let query = COLLECTION_POSTS.whereField("ownerUid", isEqualTo: "123456789").order(by: "timestamp", descending: true).limit(to: 8)
    
    if let last = lastPostDoc {
        let next = query.start(afterDocument: last)
        next.getDocuments { snapshot, _ in
            guard let documents = snapshot?.documents, !documents.isEmpty else { return }
            self.lastPostDoc = snapshot?.documents.last
            self.posts.append(contentsOf: documents.compactMap({ try? $0.data(as: Post.self) }))
        }
    }
    else
    {
        query.getDocuments { snapshot, _ in
            guard let documents = snapshot?.documents else { return }
            self.posts = documents.compactMap({ try? $0.data(as: Post.self) })
            self.lastPostDoc = snapshot?.documents.last
        }
    }
   
}
```

func() 2 :

```
func fetchScience() {
    let query = COLLECTION_POSTS.whereField("categori", isEqualTo: "Science").order(by: "timestamp", descending: true).limit(to: 8)
    
    if let last = lastDoc {
        let next = query.start(afterDocument: last)
        next.getDocuments { snapshot, _ in
            guard let documents = snapshot?.documents, !documents.isEmpty else { return }
            self.lastDoc = snapshot?.documents.last
            self.posts.append(contentsOf: documents.compactMap({ try? $0.data(as: Post.self) }))
        }
    } else {
        query.getDocuments { snapshot, _ in
            guard let documents = snapshot?.documents else { return }
            self.posts = documents.compactMap({ try? $0.data(as: Post.self) })
            self.lastDoc = snapshot?.documents.last
        }
    }
}
```

both "category" and "ownerUid" are from the same document and both are fields of type string.

[image: Fields Model]

Does anyone know why?

The only difference between these two functions is the .whereField () and that function two was integrated into my project, 1 hour ago and function one, 3 months ago.

Comment: I Tryed using this: self.posts.sorted (by: {$ 0.timestamp.dateValue ()> $ 1.timestamp.dateValue ()}),  instead of .orderBy ().

but I get the following:

"The result of the call to 'ordered (by :)' is not used"